# String Reversal Complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

I came across this question about string reversal where the original string remains the same with only the words reversed.

```
Example - Original String : "I am Sam"
          Reversed String : "I ma maS"
```

The code to achieve it is pretty simple. Just wondering what could be complexity in this case given the split and String Builder reverse method.

```
String words[] = str.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(new StringBuilder(words[i]).reverse() + " ");
        }
```

Comment: Questions regarding complexity should go in Computer Science, and requests for feedback should go in Code Review.  As a quick answer for both, this is linear in complexity, and I would recommend rewriting it to be a function that returns a String rather than printing.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding complexity:

`String.split(String)` does not support regular expressions (regexp) if your pattern is only one character long.

In such cases it use specialized code which is efficient.

Please try this code:

```
new StringBuilder(yourVariable).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: In this case the output would be `maS ma I`. In my case the string remains the same with only the words reversed

Comment: This is roughly true, but the actual conditions are "(1)one-char String and this character is not one of the RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter." ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29))